# How to load label every second in swift?

Tags: swift, string, printing, label

I have `infor` label and test.txt file content, can I set the refresher every second to load content to the label?

```
@IBOutlet weak var infor: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let test = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt")

var content = ""
do {
    content = try String(contentsOfFile: test!)
    infor.stringValue = content
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("failed to read file")
    print(error)
}
}
```

Comment: use a `Timer.scheduledTimer(....)`

Comment: Honest, yet opinion-based, question.... Why? Performance, resources, nearly everything in my instincts based on over 40 years in IT... why do you **really** need to reload something every single second your app is... well, since you didn't label this in the least mobile, I have to say "open"? You can do better. You can design better. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
  let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
    let test = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt")
    var content = ""
    do {
        content = try String(contentsOfFile: test!)
        infor.stringValue = content
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("failed to read file")
        print(error)
    }
 }
```

Comment: You might consider using `weak` reference so that the timer doesn’t keep strong reference to `self`. E.g. `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in … }`.

Comment: Force-unwrapping a `Bundle` content?

Comment: yeah, all good points. This is just an approach, a test, to show what can be done. You would not use this for real. ... test! , reload from Bundle every second, really, what next.